# Scala. Convert any val to other value in functional style

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I think that it could be useful to have method `convertTo` or other name in `Any` class, which will get function, which converts it to other val. Signature of this method could be like this (example A):

```
def convertTo[T](convertor: this.type => T) : T = convertor(this)
```

With this method developer can simply convert one object to other using convertor. In real-life world it can be used for conversion from `List[Future[T]]` to `Future[List[T]]` with this code (example B):

```
/* long code, which constructs List[Future[T]] */ convertTo { list => Future.sequence(list) }
```

instead of this (example C):

```
Future.sequence( /* long code, which constructs List[Future[T]] */ )
```

I think that code in example B is much more functional-style, that code in example C. So, I have a two questions:

1. Is it fit to functional-style coding paradigm?
2. Is there any already existed library for Scala, which provides something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Functional" means many things to many people. I think this style can (sometimes) make code more readable as it makes the code correspond more closely to the data flow, but I wouldn't describe it as "more functional".
2. How about scalaz `|>`?, e.g.

   `[code that constructs List[Future[T]]]] |> Future.sequence`

Note that this works with any function, it's not necessarily a "convertTo".

Comment: Could you give a link to documentation of scalaz `|>`?

Comment: scalaz is poorly documented; there's the scaladocs, http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.syntax.IdOps . (`IdOps` consists of scalaz methods that are pimped onto any object if you have the scalaz imports)